# App reads any file, writes to mobile but can't write to root:wheel

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, permission-denied, cydia

I have an app that writes files when needed. It is a deb package, and use to run as root using the 6755 perm after installing via cydia and running. I have transitioned over so the app is able to use substrate tweaks. In doing so writing to root:wheel folders is no longer possible. Is their a way to create a script/helper-tool/separate app/whatever that will temporarily elevate permission to write a new file and sometime overwrite the file to a root:wheel folder?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is now a tweak then you can't elevate permissions and shouldn't try to do it anyway. Many system daemons/applications use sandbox profiles which limit their access to the filesystem. Messing with owners and sandbox profiles may and will break things.

You're limited by permissions of the app your tweak is being loaded to. If you really need to write to root owned directory then the only thing I can think of is to write a helper daemon. Run it as root and use it to for writing to root directories. You will need some kind of IPC to communicate with it. There are many solutions for that, just google. That's actually how Apple does things. For example, CommCenter daemon has two helpers daemons that run as mobile and root users.

Comment: Ok I found what I was looking for, thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. Before I post another, by any chance would you know how to nslog a folder or files permissions as to mobile:mobile 501, 501.. I would like to write c++ code with if statement, as:   if (thisfile == 501,501) {nslog(@"its good");}else{ (chown(thisfile, 501,501);} i would like to see what it is prior to changing it.

Comment: 'stat' and 'chown' functions can help you with that

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. Much appreciated!